# Docusign: sharing integration key and account id between two apps?

Tags: docusignapi

I have an integration key that has been promoted to our Docusign prod account via the go live process.

I have 2 applications that need to make service requests to Docusign. Would I be able to share the user id, prod account id, and the integration key (but with different RSA key pairs) between the 2 apps? Or would this be bad practice or cause strange behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have two separate IKs (Integration Keys).

The reason is that if one app does something bad, it doesn't potentially impact the other one.

The other reason is you may want to be able to monitor each app using the API Dashboard and see how it's doing, API volumes, stats etc. Would be hard to separate the traffic if it's all the same IK.

You would have to go-live with the new IK, but since you've done this before - I'm sure you can do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Each application should have its own client id (integration key), and its own RSA key pair (if you're using JWT grant authentication).

Both applications can impersonate the same user id at the same time. Or to put it another way, a user can use more than one application at the same time.

Note that client ids are **not** limited to a particular account. Rather, one specific acccount **manages** the client id. **Any** user on any account can use the application if you give them access to the application.